# Switch off 11-minute kernel mode

Tags: linux, time, clock, ntpd

If `ntpd` works, then the kernel copies system time to hardware clock every 11   minutes. It is shown by command

```
adjtimex --print
```

I want to stop the kernel eleven mode. If I run

```
hwclock --hctosys
```

the eleven mode stops. But some time later it restores. I think, it is due to `ntpd`.

How can I stop the eleven mode forever?

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you're referring to the [11-minute clock updates in Linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/hwclock.8.html). If you want to keep `ntpd` running without updating the hardware clock, it appears the only viable option is to rebuild your kernel without the `RTC_SYSTOHC` option:

> **Set the RTC time based on NTP synchronization**
>
> If you say yes here, the system time (wall clock) will be stored
>             in the RTC specified by RTC_HCTOSYS_DEVICE approximately every 11
>             minutes if userspace reports synchronized NTP status.

This requires a rebuild, the option can't be changed using boot flags.

Alternatively, according to the [Chrony comparison information](http://chrony.tuxfamily.org/comparison.html), `openntpd` doesn't activate the kernel synchronisation.

Comment: Stephen Kitt, thanks for kernel details. Yes, I mean  11-minute clock updates in Linux. Do you think, that ntpd replaced by chrony, may solve my question  without kernel rebuilding?

Comment: @isabpchereda Chrony uses the same kernel interfaces, so it probably activates the 11-minute updates too.

Comment: More infomation with regard to "RTC kernel sync" in chrony, ntp and openntpd is at http://chrony.tuxfamily.org/comparison.html.

Comment: @isabpchereda which indicates that `openntpd` may be a solution (but I haven't tested it).

Comment: There is implementation of 11 minute mode in linux kernel: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/time/ntp.c?v=4.4#L509 `sync_cmos_clock` function

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was able to get the CMOS clock to be in localtime, without a kernel compile, by doing the following:

Make sure /etc/adjtime has 'LOCAL' and not 'UTC' (in my case, it was the last line of the file).

Make sure /etc/hardwareclock has 'localtime' in it (in my case, this was a new file and only had that line in it).

Doing the above seems to have turned off the 'NTP synch' flag in the kernel, which keeps the kernel from writing the UTC time into the CMOS clock upon shutdown. So it is highly likely that the kernel won't save the system time in the CMOS clock (I've not verified this). However, the above 2 changes appear to have turned off '11-minute mode'.

Here's the output of 'timedatectl':

```
rusty@quigon2 ~ $ timedatectl
Local time: Wed 2019-01-30 14:18:53 MST
Universal time: Wed 2019-01-30 21:18:53 UTC
RTC time: Wed 2019-01-30 14:18:50
Time zone: America/Phoenix (MST, -0700)
Network time on: yes
NTP synchronized: no
RTC in local TZ: yes

Warning: The system is configured to read the RTC time in the local time zone.
...blah blah...
```

(Note the 'NTP synchronized' info above, but also the RTC in local TZ is yes)

After all of this, you may need to fiddle with NTP or rdate or something to make sure your clock is synchronized somehow.  I leave that as an exercise for the reader.  (On my machines, I'm running 'rdate -na timemachine ; hwclock --systohc' every 30 minutes (as root).  You might be able to run NTPD in this environment and not need the rdate, but I'm not sure about the 'hwclock --systohc' - that might be needed...  Again, left as an exercise for the reader.)